# Should we add reference of achievement awarded to a project in the final project report?

Tags: publications, citations, acknowledgement, projects

My project received the third prize as part of the open project fair hosted by the entrepreneurship cell of my institution.

Is it good to add any kind of acknowledgement or reference to this achievement in the final project report which will be published via some recognised publisher?

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Is the report to a professor for a class or something that will be published?

Comment: @Buffy, yes, the project report will be published online

Comment: Just by the university, or yourself, or via some recognized publisher. I'm trying to determine how formal the process is here.

Comment: recognized publisher

Answer (score 1):

This is really just an opinion based on the comments here. I'd suggest that you leave it out of the publication, but inform the publisher's editor of the award. Ask them for advice about including it or whether the publication can add a note instead.

For a less formal "local" publication or a report to a professor, I'd suggest putting it in.

On the other hand, if I saw it in the publication, I doubt that I would object. But it doesn't really add anything to what you say in the report.